# How to package a Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle

I'm having trouble figuring out what META-INF/gradle-plugins/plugin.properties has to match. There are two issues here. One is the name of the properties file and one is the value therein set to `implementation-class`. So here is my question as succinctly as I can put it.

If I have:

```
META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.my.plugin.properties
```

What portion of the source plugin does the file name map to?  What are the implications of this name? It's source and destination? Am I doing the name correctly or should it not be so qualified?

If inside the file I have:

```
implementation-class=build.WeirdoPlugin
```

What are the source and destination of this name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`implementation-class` should point to the your main plugin class that implements`Plugin<>`

for example, in `jmeter-gradle-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/net.foragerr.FooPlugin.properties`

```
implementation-class=net.foragerr.soanswers.FooPluginImpl
```

I will then implement a class:

```
package net.foragerr.soanswers

class FooPluginImpl implements Plugin<Project>{
  ...
}
```

To use the plugin, you apply it as (in the new gradle format):

```
plugins {
  id "net.foragerr.FooPlugin" version "xxx"
}
```

Comment: ...and the domain portion has to match the package while the name portion has to match the class name. Verify?  There's a confusing example in the documentation that has an un-dotted file name. For example "file.properties" instead of "com.package.file.properties"

Comment: How gradle plugins are named has changed a bit in the last few versions. The fully qualified name including package name is the norm now. You might see simpler names for older plugins.

Comment: the string following implementation-class is really: `package.name.classname` for the class that implements the plugin. And the name of the properties file is the plugin id.

Comment: They need to fix the doggone dox then.